# how to center a HTML <form>

Tags: html, css

i have a HTML Form with some CSS styling.

but i cannot seem to make the form center in the middle of the page:

I have tried:

```
.cbp-mc-form {
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

but that didnt work - http://jsfiddle.net/uL4Sb/

Comment: give `.cbp-mc-form` a set width.

Comment: position:relatve is not required.

Answer (score 5):

It's because your form doesn't have a width. It is centered but you just can't see it because it's all over the page. Here is a JSFiddle with the solution http://jsfiddle.net/uL4Sb/3/.

```
.cbp-mc-form {
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:500px;
}
```

As you can see I just added a width. That's it!

Comment: ok lets say i add a 80% width, the form elements aren't centred in the form

Comment: `text-align: center` will center the contents of the form. `margin: 0 auto` will center the entire form inside the form's container (with form width provided)

Comment: The 80% width works fine. Here is a JSFiddle for the 80% width http://jsfiddle.net/uL4Sb/8/. If this was the right answer to your question, mark it as answer so other people with the same question can see it. Thanks in advance and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
form{
width:400px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setting the width of the form will center it

```
.cbp-mc-form {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amdorra/uL4Sb/7/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to define a width to give margin auto

here you go http://jsfiddle.net/uL4Sb/5/

```
.cbp-mc-form {
position: relative;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
border:1px solid black;
width:50%;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make form align in the middle of the page use should give width (max-width) for form.
Try :

```
.cbp-mc-form {
        position: relative;
        margin:auto;
        border:1px solid black;
        max-width: 300px;

}
```